# rails fields_for error while adding :class inside select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in `fields_for` when i add `:class=>"street"` to `text_field` it works fine, where as
when i add `:class=>"zip"` to select it is triggring error

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
    <%= person_form.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
      Street  : <%= address_fields.text_field :street, :class=>"street" %>
      Zip code: <%= address_fields.select :zip_code, :class=>"zip", options_for_select(@zip.to_a) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

please, help to solve the issue

thanks

Comment: Maybe you could post the error allso, then would be easier to answere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select):

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So, try this:

```
Zip code: <%= address_fields.select :zip_code, 
               options_for_select(@zip.to_a), {}, { :class => "zip" }
          %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Zip code: <%= address_fields.select :zip_code, options_for_select(@zip.to_a),:class=>"zip" %>
```